# How should providing a one or zero be done now that num::Zero and One are deprecated?

Tags: generics, types, numbers, rust

In writing my own generic sigma summation function to get practice with Rust, I've hit an issue with providing a seed value of zero as the accumulator.

```
fn sigma<I, T, F>(iter: I, func: F) -> T
    where I: Iterator<Item=T>,
          T: Add<Output=T>,
          F: Fn(T) -> T
{
    iter.fold(0, |acc, x| acc + func(x))
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=85b64294b5d2080974d405c23aa27ce7&version=stable&backtrace=0)

I understand that it's wrong, as 0 is a concrete type, and thus not `T`. Other answers (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27952112/2246784) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28565674/2246784)) rely on constructs like `Int::zero`, which are [deprecated](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/trait.Zero.html#tymethod.zero) as of 1.11.

There are other ways of doing this, but I am particularly interested in how it *should* be done, as testing for one, zero, or negativity is a common operation in numeric procedures that I'll hit again soon enough. Plus, now I'm curious.

My Rust version is 1.16.

Comment: Thank you for linking those questions; I've updated them appropriately.

Comment: Good rewording. Thank _you_ for answering random internet people's questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asking for how your function *should* be done can become opinion-based: there are multiple good ways of achieving this. Nevertheless, it is answerable if we narrow down to these two approaches, which I would consider typical and idiomatic:

---

`Zero` and `One` were deprecated (never even stabilized, in fact!) from the standard library mostly because there is a more generalized means of making products and sums from iterators: the [`Sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Sum.html) and [`Product`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Product.html) traits are relied upon by iterators when calling methods [`sum()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.sum) and [`product()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.product), and can even yield a result of a type other than the items'.

```
use std::iter::{Iterator, Sum};

fn sigma<I, T, F>(iter: I, func: F) -> T
    where I: Iterator<Item = T>,
          T: Sum,
          F: Fn(T) -> T
{

    iter.map(func).sum::<T>()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3496290bd5ce10d3f1addc3ff28ca53d&version=stable&backtrace=0). I took the liberty of moving the element transformation to a `map` in the iterator definition chain, thus enabling the use of `sum()` as a terminal operation.

---

The trait [`Zero`](http://rust-num.github.io/num/num/trait.Zero.html) and [`One`](http://rust-num.github.io/num/num/trait.One.html) are still available in crate `num` (or `num-traits`), so you can use that instead.

```
extern crate num;

use std::ops::Add;
use std::iter::Iterator;
use num::Zero;

fn sigma<I, T, F>(iter: I, func: F) -> T
    where I: Iterator<Item = T>,
          T: Zero + Add<Output = T>,
          F: Fn(T) -> T
{
    iter.map(func).fold(T::zero(), |a, b| a + b)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=9149680972e4a520ee4328153c541a8f&version=undefined)

Comment: A strong emphasis on the fact that the *standard libraries* `Zero` and `One` where *never* stabilized and it's always been recommended to use the `num` crate.

Comment: Using [`num-traits`](https://crates.io/crates/num-traits) is better (less dependencies), unless you want everything provided by `num` (big integer, complex, rational, ...).

Comment: Thank you; I clearly need to keep hammering on getting my traits down. And since I have you here: I'm assuming that the `.map.sum` will lead to iterating over the list twice, where as `fold` only uses a single pass?

Comment: Not really, `map` will yield a new lazy iterator that wraps the original iterator without consuming it immediately. It's more like Java's Stream#map, and unlike JavaScript's map.

Comment: Cool. I'll add for future folks: the reason being `.map` creates a `Map::Iterator` whose `.next()` lazily computes the next value from the Iterator it's wrapping, as seen in the std lib source code [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/mod.rs.html) (search for `fn next`).