# Why can't I divide a BigInt with another BigInt and save it to a variable I've initialized with zero?

Tags: rust, division, bigint

I have the following code snippet:

```
use num_bigint::*; // 0.2.2
use num_traits::*; // 0.2.8
use std::ops::*;

fn xgcd(b: &BigInt, a: &BigInt) -> (BigInt, BigInt, BigInt) {
    let mut x0: BigInt = One::one();
    let mut x1: BigInt = Zero::zero();
    let mut y0: BigInt = Zero::zero();
    let mut y1: BigInt = One::one();
    let mut q = 0;
    while a != Zero::zero() {
        q = b.div(a);
        b = a;
        a = &b.rem(a);
        x0 = x1;
        x1 = x0 - q * x1;
        y0 = y1;
        y1 = y0 - q * y1;
    }
    return (*b, x0, y0);
}
```

It gives the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:12:13
   |
12 |         q = b.div(a);
   |             ^^^^^^^^ expected integer, found struct `num_bigint::bigint::BigInt`
   |
   = note: expected type `{integer}`
              found type `num_bigint::bigint::BigInt`
```

I've looked up the documentation of [`num::BigInt`](https://docs.rs/num-bigint/0.2.2/num_bigint/struct.BigInt.html) and it states that there is in fact a `div` method with a `BigInt` as a parameter, but somehow the compiler decides not to use it and instead tells me that I can't divide a `BigInt` with a `BigInt`. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: notice how `let mut q = 0;` looks different

Comment: Besides the `q`'s type do you really want to change the value of the borrowed parameters ? Because looks like there is no implementation of `Div` and `Rem` traits for  `&mut BigInt`, you may consider creating new local vars instead

Comment: `b = a; a = b % a;` — Since `a` and `b` are the same value, won't `b % a` always result in `1`? Seems like the algorithm is off, or am I missing something?

Comment: oh yeah i figured that out too. I am trying to port over an algorithm from Python and it changes multiple variables in one line and probably made a pretty big mistake while porting

Thank you guys, I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 6):

> and instead tells me that I can't divide a `BigInt` with a `BigInt`

It does not. It tells you that the *result* of dividing the two is a `BigInt` and it needs an `{integer}`. This is because your `q` variable has been declared as an integer, not a `BigInt`. Therefore, the result of the division **must** be some kind of built-in integer (`{integer}`), but the result of dividing a `BigInt` by a `BigInt` is another `BigInt`.

You've used `Zero::zero` everywhere else, so it's unclear why you didn't use it here. Fortunately, you don't need to set it anything because you shouldn't initialize it until inside the loop anyway:

```
use num_bigint::*; // 0.2.2
use num_traits::*; // 0.2.8

fn xgcd(b: &BigInt, a: &BigInt) -> (BigInt, BigInt, BigInt) {
    let mut a = a.clone();
    let mut b = b.clone();
    let mut x0 = BigInt::one();
    let mut x1 = BigInt::zero();
    let mut y0 = BigInt::zero();
    let mut y1 = BigInt::one();

    while !a.is_zero() {
        let q = &b / &a;
        b = a.clone();
        a = &b % &a;
        x0 = x1.clone();
        x1 = &x0 - &q * x1;
        y0 = y1.clone();
        y1 = &y0 - &q * y1;
    }

    (b, x0, y0)
}
```

Changes include:

- The operator forms are used instead of the method names (e.g. `/` vs `div`).
- A number of `.clone()` calls were added. I didn't ensure that these were the minimal number of clones possible, so check that.
- A number of `&` were added to prevent clones in other places.
- [`Zero::is_zero`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/0.2.8/num_traits/identities/trait.Zero.html#tymethod.is_zero) can be faster than creating a value and comparing it.
- The shorter syntax of `BigInt::zero()` is used.

See also:

- [How do I use integer number literals when using generic types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28565440/155423)
- [Cannot create a generic function that uses a literal zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27952003/155423)
- [Rust, compute gcd: modularity, references](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/186382/32521)

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't notice at all that I didn't use Zero::zero() for declaring q. I just started learning Rust and the concepts of the language are still pretty new to me. You really helped me understand that part better.