# an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types, or, how to add +1 to a generic type T

Tags: rust

I'm trying to do something generic for numbers which involves adding `0` and `1` to the type `T`. However:

```
use std::ops::{AddAssign, MulAssign};

pub struct Profiler<T: Default + Copy + Eq> {
    something: T
}

impl<T: Default + Copy + Eq + AddAssign<T> + MulAssign<T>> Profiler<T> {

    pub fn plus_one(x: &mut T) {
        *x += 1 as T;
    }

    pub fn to_zero(x: &mut T) {
        *x *= 0 as T;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=260bcbcaf6c74c4758d79a796150fca8)

I get this error:

```
error[E0605]: non-primitive cast: `i32` as `T`
  --> src/lib.rs:10:15
   |
10 |         *x += 1 as T;
   |               ^^^^^^ an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types or to coerce to a specific trait object

error[E0605]: non-primitive cast: `i32` as `T`
  --> src/lib.rs:14:15
   |
14 |         *x *= 0 as T;
   |               ^^^^^^ an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types or to coerce to a specific trait object

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

How can I tell the compiler that `T` is a primitive type? I guess this is what's missing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot create a generic function that uses a literal zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952003/cannot-create-a-generic-function-that-uses-a-literal-zero)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well just because something supports add-assign doesn't mean it could possibly understand how to "+1" it. What if `T` refers to a 3x3 matrix? How would `1 as T` make sense in that case?

So if you really want to support +1, then your type should *also* implement `From<i32>` or whatever.

Or maybe you want to restrict `T` to primitive numerical types?

Comment: Yes, but is it possible to restrict `T` to primitive numerical types?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to restrict T to a numerical type:

Using the crate `num_traits`, you can use Num as a trait to restrict T to numerical types, with `<T: num_traits::Num>`.

[Documentation of Num](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/trait.Num.html)